# Group a column such that its sum is approximately equal in each group

Tags: python, pandas

What's the easiest way to sort evenly distributed values into a predefined number of groups?

```
data = {'impact':[10,30,20,10,90,60,50,40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'])

print df

   impact
a      10
b      30
c      20
d      10
e      90
f      60
g      50
h      40

numgroups = 4

group_targetsum = round(df.impact.sum() / numgroups, -1)

print group_targetsum

80.0
```

In the case above, I'd like to create 4 groups from df.  The only sorting criteria is that the sum of impact in each group should be approximately equal to group_targetsum.  impact sum can be above or below group_targetsum within a reasonable margin.

Ultimately, I'd like to separate these groups into their own dataframes, preserving index.  Resulting in something like this:

```
print df_a

   impact
e      90

print df_b

   impact
c      20
f      60

print df_c

   impact

a      10
d      10
g      50

print df_d

   impact

b      30
h      40
```

Resulting dataframes don't need to be exactly this, just as long as they sum as close as possible to group_targetsum.

Comment: What is your desired output for the example you give with `numgroups = 4`?

Comment: I edited above to hopefully clarify a little.

Comment: It seems this solution is what you would like, which is derived from @Divakar's solution to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67816898/943773

Answer (score 4):

Assuming fairly similar values in the series, here's an approach using [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) -

```
In [150]: df
Out[150]: 
   impact
a      10
b      30
c      20
d      10
e      90
f      60
g      50
h      40

In [151]: a = df.values.ravel()

In [152]: shift_num = group_targetsum*np.arange(1,numgroups)

In [153]: idx = np.searchsorted(a.cumsum(), shift_num,'right')

In [154]: np.split(a, idx)
Out[154]: [array([10, 30, 20, 10]), array([90]), array([60]), array([50, 40])]
```

Comment: I'm glad I'm thinking along the same lines.  I messed it up because I tried to sharpen the line.  Instead of `[80, 160, 240, 320]` I used `[310/4, 310/2, 310 * 3/4, 310]`.  In this case, `searchsorted` identifies the same index twice.  Basically try it with `group_targetsum = a.sum() / 4`.  The real answer to this needs to ultimately include some fuzzy decisions around corner cases.

Comment: @piRSquared Agreed, this might mess up with big numbers at potential interval points.

Comment: Ha, I played around with this awhile before exploring your answer and now see that I have conceptually done things the same as you did for the most part (just doing it in pandas instead of numpy).  However, I think you might like how I did the adjustment for midpoint which I believe will usually group things more evenly.  Without the midpoint adjustment, I would get the same answer as what you would get if you left off the 'right' option from `searchsorted`

Comment: @JohnE Yeah the moment I saw yours, it looked similar :) Well, I need to look into your midpoint thing in more detail, but I will take your word on it for now.

Comment: Thanks.  I see how that groups the values, but not sure how I can use this while preserving the original index.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually we'd just like to use a weighted version of `qcut`, but that doesn't exist in pandas at this time.  Nevertheless, we can accomplish the same thing by combining `cumsum` and `cut`.  The `cumsum` essentially gives us the weighting, and we then slice it up with `cut`.

(Note about 'csum_midpoint':  without the midpoint adjustment, we'll end up putting things into groups based on where it begins (in a cumulative sense) and hence end up with a bias towards binning in the higher groups.  The midpoint adjustment can't make things perfectly even, but it helps.  I believe this answer is mathematically the same as @Divakar's with the exception of my use of midpoint here and his use of 'right'.)

```
df['csum'] = df['impact'].cumsum()
df['csum_midpoint'] = (df.csum + df.csum.shift().fillna(0)) / 2.

df['grp'] = pd.cut( df.csum_midpoint, np.linspace(0,df['impact'].sum(),numgroups+1 ))
df.groupby( df.grp )['impact'].sum()

grp
(0, 77.5]       70
(77.5, 155]     90
(155, 232.5]    60
(232.5, 310]    90
Name: impact, dtype: int64

df

   impact  csum  csum_midpoint           grp
a      10    10            5.0     (0, 77.5]
b      30    40           25.0     (0, 77.5]
c      20    60           50.0     (0, 77.5]
d      10    70           65.0     (0, 77.5]
e      90   160          115.0   (77.5, 155]
f      60   220          190.0  (155, 232.5]
g      50   270          245.0  (232.5, 310]
h      40   310          290.0  (232.5, 310]
```