# Group rows consecutively into near equal sum

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a group column attribute where each groups cumulative sum is as equal as possible between the groups. The row order must not change.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"id":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        "area":[489.8,1099,1004,37.2,371.3,2390.5,2500,2500,1298.7,1125.7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   id    area
0   1   489.8
1   2  1099.0
2   3  1004.0
3   4    37.2
4   5   371.3
5   6  2390.5
6   7  2500.0
7   8  2500.0
8   9  1298.7
9  10  1125.7
numgroups = 3 #I want this number of groups
group_area_target = df.area.sum()/numgroups
#4272

My goal is to create the group column:

#df["group"] = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]
#     id    area  group
# 0   1   489.8      1
# 1   2  1099.0      1
# 2   3  1004.0      1
# 3   4    37.2      1
# 4   5   371.3      1
# 5   6  2390.5      2
# 6   7  2500.0      2
# 7   8  2500.0      3
# 8   9  1298.7      3
# 9  10  1125.7      3

#sums = df.groupby("group")["area"].sum()
# group
# 1    3001.3
# 2    4890.5
# 3    4924.4

#The total deviation from target is (sums-group_area_target).abs().sum() 2541
```

I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639804/group-a-column-such-that-its-sum-is-approximately-equal-in-each-group) which roughly suggests:

```
a = df.area.values
shift_num = group_area_target*np.arange(1, numgroups)
idx = np.searchsorted(a.cumsum(), shift_num,'right').tolist()

for e, i in enumerate(idx,1):
    df.loc[i, "group"] = e

sums2 = df.groupby("group")["area"].sum()
#The total deviation is (sums2-group_area_target).abs().sum() 3695
    
df.group = df.group.bfill().fillna(df.group.max()+1)
   id    area  group
0   1   489.8    1.0
1   2  1099.0    1.0
2   3  1004.0    1.0
3   4    37.2    1.0
4   5   371.3    1.0
5   6  2390.5    1.0
6   7  2500.0    2.0
7   8  2500.0    2.0
8   9  1298.7    3.0
9  10  1125.7    3.0

#The total deviation is (sums2-group_area_target).abs().sum() 3695
```

So the result is less optimal than the manual assignment of groups. How can I automate finding the best solution?

Comment: It's difficult to get the "best" result in a vectorial way. Do you want the minimal deviation between sums? You'll have to compute many combinations are compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the best combination, you need to test all possible splits. For that `itertools.combinations` is useful. I'm using the minimal standard deviation as indication of the best split.

```
from itertools import combinations, pairwise

N = 3
def group(s):
    def f(c):
        pairs = pairwise((0, *c, len(s)))
        return np.std([s.iloc[slice(*p)].sum() for p in pairs])
    best = min(combinations(range(1, len(s)-1), N-1), key=f)
    out = np.zeros(len(s), dtype=int)
    out[list(best)] = 1
    return np.cumsum(out)+1

df['group'] = group(df['area'])
```

Output:

```
   id    area  group
0   1   489.8      1
1   2  1099.0      1
2   3  1004.0      1
3   4    37.2      1
4   5   371.3      1
5   6  2390.5      2
6   7  2500.0      2
7   8  2500.0      3
8   9  1298.7      3
9  10  1125.7      3
```